# VBA how to use a dictionary

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I am getting issues in using a dictionary in VBA. I want to add values from a sheet to a dictionary. If I use simple lists, there is no error in the code. Like this.

```
Function Account(Place As String) As String

Dim cities(500)
Dim accounts(500)

For i = 2 To 500
    cities(i) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value
    accounts(i) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value
Next i

placeName = StrConv(Place, vbProperCase)
Account = placeName

End Function
```

This code does not give an issue but if I add the code for the dictionary, there is some issue.

```
Function Account(Place As String) As String

Dim cities(500)
Dim accounts(500)
Dim dict
Set dict = CreateObject(Scripting.Dictionary)

For i = 2 To 500
    cities(i) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value
    accounts(i) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value
    dict(cities(i)) = accounts(i)
Next i

placeName = StrConv(Place, vbProperCase)
Account = placeName
dict = Nothing

End Function
```

Can someone point out the error. I am new to vba so I dont know much about it.

Comment: dict.add cities(i), accounts(i)

Comment: @DaveClough I still have the same issue

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @DaveClough when I use the function, the column just says #VALUE!. Im not sure what the error is.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the dictionary ?

Comment: @h2so4 I want to get values from another sheet, and check if they are in the dictionary or not. If they do I want their corresponding value.

Comment: The operable code looks correct although it should be noted that a duplicate cities value will only retain the last accounts value. You just need to `Set dict = Nothing`. VBA Sets objects, you cannot assign Nothing with an equals.

Comment: BTW, this looks like a good place to put [Declaring Variables - When to use a Static variable](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/16978/when-to-use-a-static-variable) to good use.

Comment: @Jeeped there are no duplicate values. And the issue still exists even after i used `Set dict = Nothing`. Also I am using the function is "Sheet1" and getting the values from "Sheet2".

Comment: tbbh, I don't see the point of the function at all. You mess around with two arrays and a dictionary object but all you actually accomplish is changing the *Place* parameter passed into the function to proper case. The worksheet's PROPER function can accomplish that.

Comment: @Jeeped In the end I want to get rid of using the arrays and check if the value of the place parameter exists in the dictionary or not. I just posted this part of the code as it is the part in which I am getting the error. Printing the Place parameter is to see if the function runs properly or not.

Comment: I am still puzzled by what you try to achieve with this function ? Anyhow your instruction to define the dictionary object is not correct and should read Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") and not Set dict = CreateObject(Scripting.Dictionary) the quotes are missing

Comment: ^ that. `CreateObject` takes a progId **string literal**. But if you're trying to figure out how a dictionary works, why not start with early binding so you get IntelliSense? Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime - that said I don't think anyone has a different version of that library unless they're running Windows < 98, so there's no need to use late-binding for it - the same version is on every single Windows box ever manufactured in this century.

Answer (score 3):

The folowing UDF loads a dictionary object with places as keys (unique) and associated accounts as items. After the dictionary has been loaded, it looks up the *Place* parameter passed into the function and returns the account if found.

```
Option Explicit

Function Account(Place As String) As String
    Static d As Long, dict As Object

    If dict Is Nothing Then
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    Else
        dict.RemoveAll
    End If

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For d = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            dict.Item(.Cells(d, "B").Value2) = .Cells(d, "C").Value2
        Next d
    End With

    If dict.exists(Place) Then
        Account = dict.Item(Place)
    Else
        Account = "not found"
    End If

End Function
```

Note that beyond other corrections, the code to instantiate the dictionary object is `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` not `CreateObject(Scripting.Dictionary)`.

Comment: Beyond an intellectual exercise, this function  is pointless. A VLOOKUP worksheet function accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

One possible area of concern, brought to mind by one of your comments, lies in the use of "Sheet1" and "Sheet2". In Excel VBA, there are two different ways to refer to a worksheet. The is the Name of the worksheet, which is what the user sees on the tabs in Excel, and the user can change at will. Thtese default to names like "Sheet1", "Sheet2", etc.

There is also the "Codename" for each worksheet. In the Visual Basic Editor, the project explorer window will list all the worksheets under "Microsoft Excel Objects". There you'll see the Codename for each worksheet, with the Name of the worksheet in parentheses.

When you use Worksheets("Sheet1"), the "Sheet1" refers to the Name, not the Codename. It's possible to end up with a worksheet with the Name "Sheet1" and the  codename "Sheet2".

As far as your functions are concerned, I note that in both cases you declare local variables -- the arrays 'cities' and 'accounts' in the first, and those two plus the dictionary 'dict' in the second. You have code to fill those local variables, but then do nothing with them. The return value of the function is not dependent on any of those local variables.

Once the function code completes, those local variables lose their values. VBA returns the memory it used to store those variables to its pool of available memory, to be reused for other purposes.

Try commenting-out the entire for...next loop, and you'll see that the value return from the function is unchanged.

I'm not certain what you intend to accomplish in these functions. It would be helpful for you to explain that.